# Как сделать fullscreen page при помощи flex

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

**Не могу отцентрить как нужно блоки в фулскрин странице**

Кода не приложу ибо вообще ничего не получилось разумного
Вобщем тема такая вот набросал макет как все задумывается:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

div с h1 должен быть отцентрован горизонтально и вертикально
а div с p должен быть приклеяным как бы к низу ну и смаргином каким нибуть

Все это должно находиться в div Content с какимнибуть фоном

И самое главное все это должно быть на всю страницу и адаптивным

для решения проблемы пытался использовать flex но он центрует сразу и h1 и p вместе а надо чтоб один по центру а другой снизу

**использование такого костыля как pos-relativ потом pos-a и отриц маргины не вариант потому как высота H1 и P не статичны(не известны изначально)**

Пожалуйста помогите сделать это адаптивным

Comment: Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/3yvhwwzL/

Comment: @soledar10 дело в том что блока два один по центру другой снизу а у вас три

Comment: @VipFilStar почему именно на флекс ? на table-cell тоже самое можно сделать и по верьте даже браузера типа Midori даже будут понимать это

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.** Заголовок будет отцентрован, а описание прижато к низу по центру, этот вариант, если блок контента имеет фиксированную высоту, в данном случае fullscreen высота и ширина блока должны быть растянуты по всему экрану. Преимущество в том, что заголовок будет всегда строго по центру, в независимости от получившейся высоты блока.

```css
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(//images.pexels.com/photos/45875/raspberries-berries-fruits-red-45875.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Описание</p>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2.** Если высота блока всё же может быть любой, то самое простое решение будет отцентровка с прижимом к нижней части, но тогда придётся будет для заголовка и описания добавлять `margon-top`, чтобы отделять их друг от друга. Преимущество в том, что можно выставить необходимые отступы и блок по высоте будет растягиваться автоматически.

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(//images.pexels.com/photos/45875/raspberries-berries-fruits-red-45875.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  padding: 20px;
}

h1,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Описание</p>
</div>
```